# How can I submit two or more input files to a pipeline in a bash script?

Tags: bash, loops

I have written a bash script that performs a series of bioinformatics tasks using various programs. I would like to know how to pass this script a string of filenames to perform the same analysis on consecutively.

i.e. assuming I have something like:

```
name=a.txt
echo "this is a test" >> $name
echo "this is also a test" >> $name
echo "this is still a test" >> $name
```

I thought I could do:

```
for i in 'b.txt c.txt d.txt'
    do
    name=$i
        echo "this is a loop test" >> $name
        echo "this is also a loop test" >> $name
        echo "this is still a loop test" >> $name
    done
```

to achieve the same sort of thing. but obviously this doesnt work. How may I achieve this?

Thanks,

Matt

Comment: That's 3 input files, not 2 - you can't fool me ;-)

Comment: @MarkSetchell, Thanks you're right, foiled! I've edited to reflect the true nature of the question ;)

Comment: Your only error is the single quotes. Get rid of them. You're specifying a single filename called `b.txt c.txt d.txt`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example seems mostly correct if I understand what you want to do.
To get the list of files from command line arguments you can do like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
for file in "$@"; do
  echo "text" >> $file
done
```

Comment: Yes this seems to have worked, thanks and thanks to @ooga for the same advice aswell!

Answer (score 0):

the quotes around your filenames are the problem, without them it works